# Method creating CountDownTimer objects

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I'm kinda stuck with the following code. My goal is to create multiple CountDownTimer objects and start them after each other. The method looks like that:

```
    private CountDownTimer setUpCountdown(int duration, int tick) {
    // when tick is not set, set it to default 1 second
    tick = (tick == 0 ? 1 : tick);

    // convert seconds to milliseconds and set up the timer
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(duration*1000, tick*1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (countdown != null) {
                int timeRemaining = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                countdown.setText(String.valueOf(timeRemaining));
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            // hide the countdown button and remove it from baseLayout. set the background of baseLayout back to black
            countdown.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            baseLayout.removeView(countdown);
            baseLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    };

    return timer;
}
```

Then I create two timers:

```
CountDownTimer timer1 = setUpCountdown(8,1);
timer1.start();
CountDownTimer timer2 = setUpCountdown(5,1);
timer2.start();
```

When running the code the output for those values is: 4..3..2..1..3 when it should be 7..6...1 4...1 When I'm using 10 and 5 seconds as duration I get a single Countdown on the android device that counts from 10 to 5. It looks like the objects I'm creating are not really independent from each other or (kind of) use the same variables. Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting two timer at same time and displaying their values in single `textView` so you are able to see the value of only second timer `4..1` then the remaining values of timer with `8` sec will be displayed as `3..1`

```
timer 7 6 5 4  3 2 1
// timer 2 will reset the values in text view, then after 1, you will see 3 2 1
timer 4 3 2 1
```

You can use `Toast` to verify the behavior or you have to use different `TextViews` to achieve the desired result or  to achieve desired behavior, you can create and start the second timer from `onFinish()`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So android isn't waiting for the first countdown to finish and updates the textview "simultaneously"? Is it possible to make the second CountDownTimer object wait for the first one to finish without starting the second countdown in the first's OnFinish-method?

Comment: @chh yes, to achieve desired behavior, you can create and start the second timer from `onFinish()`

Comment: @chh you got it, great , i am glad that i could help, happy coding